# Using method_exchangeImplementations with block_invoke methods

Tags: objective-c, hook

I'm trying to replace method implementation with the following code

```
BOOL ct_hookMethod(Class originalClass, SEL originalSelector, Class swizzledClass, SEL swizzledSelector)
{
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(originalClass, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(swizzledClass, swizzledSelector);

    if (originalMethod && swizzledMethod)
    {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

It works for selectors like `-[xxxView runRequest:]`, but not for methods like `-[xxView runRequest:]_block_invoke:`.

Does anyone know how to hook them?

Comment: This should work no problem?

Comment: @OlSen It seems to be dispatch_once, but I'm not sure